# Power Saving mode after start-up (12.04.4)

Tags: startup, gnome-power-manager

I have and issue that I can't seem to find right answer to. Immediately after purple loading screen I get an notification "Entering power saving mode", and I can't do nothing about it. If it's of any help I had graphic driver issues that I solved right before power saving issues. I can access command line over tty and give more info, just tell me what info please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to disable power management from Start-up applications? You should also look in there for conflicting programs related to power management. Some people also try to enable hibernate in Ubuntu 12.04.4, and this could generate some issues also.

Comment: In Start-up apps I only have Guake Terminal. And as for the power management only setting set is 'Never go to suspend'.

Comment: Try to install in a terminal this package: **sudo apt-get install gnome-power-manager**  . It should be already present on your system,  and if it is then you can open it and try to adjust your power settings according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue. I reinstalled `xserver-xorg` (`sudo aptitude reinstall xserver-xorg`). I dont't know how was issue fixed by performing this action, but it's fixed. It would be nice if someone could provide enlightenment regarding this issue and this solution.

If you ask me why I reinstalled `xserver-xorg`, the answer is because I previously had issues with proprietary graphic drivers, and after I fixed them, I reinstalled `xserver-xorg`. Everything worked fine until first restart, and the rest is start of this thread. That is the reason for my action.

Again, this is just a solution that helped me solve this threads issue, it might not be recommended or even right, I think I owe an answer since I found one. Cheers.